# Download and store JSON file from url. PHP

Tags: php, json, web-services

In my project, I have to get and store the JSON data from a URL. I have managed to get the JSON data using file_get_contents. Now I wish to store the retrieved data into a folder in JSON format. Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`file_put_contents()` will work just fine.

```
file_put_contents('someFileName.json', $yourStringOfJson);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php